# Function cut applied to one column using breaks values from other colunms

Tags: r, data.table, cut

Say I have this database:

```
Bins=10
df=data.frame(Min=c(0,10,20,30), Max=c(5,16,26,38),val=c(3,11,21,31))
```

I want to add another column, in which I categorize the values in one column (i.e., column call "val"), by the equal size bins created between the values in two other columns (i.e., the breaks between columns call Min and Max.

I thought I could just use the cut function defining as breaks the sequence between the Min and Max columns, but it does not work.

```
df$bin=cut(df$val, breaks = seq(from = df$Min, to =df$Max,length.out =Bins) ,include.lowest =TRUE)
```

Any idea how can I define the breaks used by the function cut on each row?.

Comment: I believe you can use `dplyr::rowwise()`.. but you are looking for a single interval for each row, correct?  Please check if below is your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mutate()` with `rowwise()` from `dplyr` package.

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(bin=cut(val, breaks = seq(from = Min, to =Max,length.out =Bins) ,include.lowest =TRUE))
```

Output:

```
    Min   Max   val bin        
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>      
1     0     5     3 (2.78,3.33]
2    10    16    11 (10.7,11.3]
3    20    26    21 (20.7,21.3]
4    30    38    31 (30.9,31.8]
```

If, instead of the `bin` column showing a factor variable's range , you could do this to have `bin` be the midpoint of that range:

```
f <- function(s,e,b,val) {
  x = seq(s,e,length.out = b)
  max(x[x<val]) + (min(x[x>val])-max(x[x<val]))/2
}

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(bin=f(Min, Max, Bins, val))
```

Output:

```
    Min   Max   val   bin
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     5     3  3.06
2    10    16    11 11   
3    20    26    21 21   
4    30    38    31 31.3
```

Comment: Can you think of a way to put the labels as the mid-point of the range, in this setting for the cut function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. the mid point of the range in the `bin` column is just the value in the `val` column?

Comment: The mid-point of the range does not need to be the Val value. Keep in mint that the Val value simply fall in that range...it does not need to be the mid-point exactly.

Comment: got it. you are correct.. sorry.. I've edited my answer to try and provide you a solution to that follow up question

Comment: wow...that is pretty good...thank you